# Clara.io exported object not visible in Three.JS canvas - Only black square

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using [Three.JS](http://threejs.org/) and imported an object which was exported as a JSON from [clara.io](https://clara.io/). My problem is that the object is not visible in the canvas and all I get is a black square with the same size I set in the variable (400 and 300 pixels).

Here's my code:

```
    var WIDTH = 400,
      HEIGHT = 300;

    // set some camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
      ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
      NEAR = 1,
      FAR = 100000;


    var $container = $('#wrapper');


    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    var camera =
      new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        VIEW_ANGLE,
        ASPECT,
        NEAR,
        FAR);

     scene = new THREE.Scene();
     scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);
     camera.position.z = 300;
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.z = 100;


    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    $container.append(renderer.domElement);

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
    scene.add(ambientLight);


    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("js/suzanne-blender.json", function (obj) {

        scene.add(obj)
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

What I expect to see is the model with the material as I exported it from clari.io. Thanks.

[Here's a link to the object JSON file](http://ge.tt/3e22rUo1/v/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the JSON by loading it into the ThreeJS editor here: http://threejs.org/editor/ (just drag and drop it.)  I then added a single light and dragged the light to not be exactly at the center.  I could see the Suzanne model fine in the editor.  This means that the issue must be in the code you are using to visualize the model.  Maybe you just need to add a point light that is off to one side to light the object properly?

Best regards,

Ben Houston